# Groovy regex not matching

Tags: regex, groovy

I have `rpm` packages that are named like `pkg-name.0.15.0-6.x86_64.rpm`. I want to extract two strings out of this:

1. Just the name without version, release, or architecture. So in this case it would be `pkg-name`
2. Then I want to extract the name with the version and release. So in this case it would be `pkg-name.0.15.0-6`

I tried this code below but I am not getting any match and I cannot figure out why

```
fullRpmName = "pkg-name.0.15.0-6.x86_64.rpm"
def matcher = (fullRpmName =~ /((.*)\\.\\d+\\.\\d+.\\d+-\\d+\\..*).x86_64\\.rpm/)
println matcher.group(1)
println matcher.group(2)
```

Comment: Your regex [does not match](https://regex101.com/r/Kf7ZQC/1) the string. `^((.*?)\..*)\.x86_64\.rpm` will do, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kf7ZQC/2).

Answer (score 1):

I modified your regex to match the package naming convention, you can see a working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/h4o5tS/1):

```
((.*)\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+-\d+)\.x86_64\.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String fullRpmName = "pkg-name.0.15.0-6.x86_64.rpm"
    def matcher = fullRpmName =~ /^((.*?)\..*)\.x86_64\.rpm/
    if (matcher) {
        println matcher.group(2) // pkg-name
        println matcher.group(1) // pkg-name.0.15.0-6
}
```

See the [Groovy demo online](https://ideone.com/qNajAM). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kf7ZQC/2).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `((.*?)\..*)` - Group 1:

  - `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\.x86_64\.rpm` - a `.x86_64.rpm` string.

A bit more complex is a regex like `^(([^.]*)(?:[-.]\d+)*)\.x86_64\.rpm` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kf7ZQC/3)):

- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than a dot
- `(?:[-.]\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a `-` or `.` followed with one or more digits.